# Moving a sprite using math in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am currently making a game in Unity, where characters are moving towards a point at the bottom of the screen, from a random x-position at the top of the screen. As they have to keep a constant speed (and later on possibly be able to move in specific patterns), I cannot use `Vector3.Lerp`for this.

Instead, I tried using some simple math. `StaticInfo.instance.GetPlayerPosition()` is the targeted position. The code happens in the character's FixedUpdate().

```
float aVal = (myTransform.localPosition.y - StaticInfo.instance.GetPlayerPosition().y) / 
             (myTransform.localPosition.x - StaticInfo.instance.GetPlayerPosition().x);
float degrees = Mathf.Atan(aVal) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(myTransform.localPosition.x - (distance * speed * Mathf.Cos(degrees)), 
                             myTransform.localPosition.y - (distance * speed * Mathf.Sin(degrees)), 
                             1);
myTransform.localPosition = newPos;
```

My problem is when these characters are created (instantiated from prefab), they make a small 180-degrees loop before moving in the wanted direction. After that, they move exactly as wanted.

Is using math the best solution? And if it is, why does it do a funky drift when initialized?

Comment: Try using Atan2(y,x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a more simple solution to what you are trying to achieve:

```
    Vector3 moveDirection = (StaticInfo.instance.GetPlayerPosition() - myTransform.localPosition).normalized;

    Vector3 newPos = myTransform.localPosition + moveDirection * distance * speed;

    myTransform.localPosition = newPos;
```

If you want the object to point in the direction of the movement you can do:

```
myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, Mathf.atan2(moveDirection.y, moveDirection.x)*Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90); // may not need to offset by 90 degrees here;
```

Comment: `moveDirection` needs to be normalized.

Comment: Now you need the transforms forward direction to always face moveDirection. Which is what his problem was. Still, this is simpler for the movement part.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks